# Access databricks secret in custom python package imported into databricks notebook

Tags: python, databricks, azure-databricks

We have a custom python package hosted on a private bitbucket repo, which can be installed via `%pip install git+https//...` on any databricks notebook.

One of the functions performs a number of operations and then pushes data to another location, for which credentials are required. When the function is run, e.g., locally, this is handled via config files, but if the function runs on databricks we'd like to store these credentials in a databricks secret (scope).

However, trying to do something like

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
spark = SparkSession(sc)
from pyspark.dbutils import DBUtils
dbutils = DBUtils(spark)
pw = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = <SCOPE>, key = <KEY>)
```

within the module (foo) doesn't work and causes the following error:

```
>>>import myPackage
>>>myPackage.foo.bar()

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o272.get.
    : java.lang.SecurityException: Accessing a secret from Databricks Connect requires
    a privileged secrets token. To obtain such a token, you can run the following
    in a Databricks workspace notebook:
```

given that we possibly would like to run this function regularly using a scheduled job creating a time-limited privileged token doesn't seem to be the way to go.

Is there a way to make this work or is there an alternative/better approach that we should be following instead?

Comment: have you tried to execute that code in the notebook?

Comment: hey @alex, no, because dbutils is available directly in the notebook. When running the code above I do get the same error, however, so it probably should not have come as a surprise that it doesn't work after importing, either

Comment: if you're doing that in the notebooks, then you don't need to import it...

Comment: I'm not, though. I just tested it to answer the question. The idea is that this package, which usually is only used locally, can be used in Databricks, too.

Answer (score 1):

For others that might run into the same problem in the future. Using this code snippet within my function ended up working for me:

```
import IPython
dbutils = IPython.get_ipython().user_ns["dbutils"]
```